# CursorLoader versus CursorAdapter on Loading Big Databases?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-loader

For example, I'm dealing with some kind of 'Logs' growing slowly, say, less than 20/day. Due to the need of offline usability they are synchronized and stored in an database regularly. In my opinion users in most times are only interested in about the first 60 items (3 days), but sometimes they needs to check a particular item long long ago. So now I have these objects:

- Local storage, infrequent update.
- High frequency query in short range, low frequency query in long range.

I think it's kind of waste to load too many items (say 200+) just on first seen, so Adapters might be more suitable. I can load first 60 and when user scrolls to the bottom load the next 60.

But meanwhile Loaders seems more recommended by Google and easier to realize than Adapter. And it uses async load methods, which is useful in some place. So which one is the best practice for this sense? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: `"CursorLoader versus CursorAdapter"`, no versus, `CursorLoader` in 99% cases works with `CursorAdapter` - the former produces the `Cursor` which is used by the latter

Comment: @pskink Er, it seems so. But how to make those two work to load in segments (load on demand) ?

Comment: you dont have to do that: see `SQLiteCursor` class: it extends `AbstractWindowedCursor` which means that if your data working set if really huge only small segment of your data is kept by your cursor (inside `CursorWindow`) and loaded on demand when you iterate the cursor

Comment: @pskink huge thanks! That's actually what I need. I thought the window function should be realized by the cursorloader, read the code and found nothing... Thanks again! And now should I delete this question?